# iOS ListView Context Action does not swipe back automatically in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In `Xamarin Forms` (using `Prism`, although not necessarily needed), I want to dynamically change `MenuItem` `ContextActions` from items in a `ListView`:

### MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="XamarinProject.Views.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
Title="MainPage"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <ListView
        x:Name="mList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding CurrentCommand}" Text="{Binding Cycle}" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding State}" TextColor="Navy" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>();

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Items.Add(new MyItemViewModel(_pageDialogService));
    }
}
```

### MyItemViewModel

```
public class MyItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _cycle;

    public string Cycle
    {
        get { return _cycle; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _cycle, value); }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _currentCommand;
    private readonly DelegateCommand[] _commands;
    public DelegateCommand CurrentCommand
    {
        get { return _currentCommand; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentCommand, value); }
    }

    public MyItemViewModel(IPageDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _commands = new DelegateCommand[]
        {
            new DelegateCommand(show1),
            new DelegateCommand(show2),
            new DelegateCommand(show3)
        };
        show1();
    }

    private void show1()
    {
        show("1", 1, "I show 1");
    }

    private void show2()
    {
        show("2", 2, "I show 2");
    }

    private void show3()
    {
        show("3", 0, "I show 3");
    }

    private void show(string cycle, int newIndex, string message)
    {
        Cycle = cycle;
        CurrentCommand = _commands[newIndex];
        // dialogService available through Unity, it's available
        _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Alert", message, "Ok");
    }
}
```

However, on iOS, when I swipe I row so I see the `ContextAction(s)`, and I tick it, it executes the `Command`, but the `ContextActionMenu`/row is not automatically swiped back, as it should be. If I bind it to a single `DelegateCommand`, without changing its reference dynamically to another `DelegateCommand`, it works just fine (like this in XAML: `Command={Binding MyNonChangingCommand}`). How can one fix this, so that the row is automatically "swiped back" (like it's supposed to)? Or is it just a bug in either Prism or Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Prism is an MVVM Framework and wouldn't be responsible for UI Presentation issues, though there are on occasion some tricks you may need to do with MasterDetailPages and NavigationPages to have them display the way you want with Prism.

With regards to your code you would likely want to make a few changes.

- There is a difference between ViewModels and Models. For Instance you may have a Monkey model, with a MonkeyListViewModel, and a MonkeyDetailViewModel. The MonkeyListViewModel would contain an `ObservableCollection<Monkey>` and one or more commands to execute for a particular Monkey
- You need to create a `DataTemplateSelector` that contains the business logic for your model and can pick the appropriate selector (see below)

Model

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class SomeItemListPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> SomeItems { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<SomeItem> MyCommand { get; }

    private void OnMyCommandExecuted( SomeItem item )
    {
        // Do Foo
    }
}
```

DataTemplateSelector

```
public class MyItemCellSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate( object item, BindableObject container )
    {
        var myItem = item as MyItem;

        if( myItem.SomeProperty == true )
            return Foo;

        return Bar;
    }

    public DataTemplate Foo { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate Bar { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:MyApp.Selectors;assembly=MyApp"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Name="page"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.SomeItemListPage">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <!-- Sets up the Foo Template that has no Context Actions -->
      <DataTemplate x:Key="fooTemplate">
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>

      <!-- Sets up the Bar Template that has the Do Foo Context Action which executes
            MyCommand from the ViewModel -->
      <DataTemplate x:Key="barTemplate">
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}">
          <TextCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Text="Do Foo" 
              Command="{Binding BindingContext.MyCommand,Source={x:Reference page}}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
          </TextCell.ContextActions>
        </TextCell>  
      </DataTemplate>

      <!-- Sets up the Selector to us the defined Templates for my Foo and Bar conditions -->
      <selector:MyItemCellSelector x:Key="myItemSelector"
                                   Default="{StaticResource fooTemplate}"
                                   PendingUpload="{StaticResource barTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource localInspectionSelector}">
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: While this works fine at ListView's creation time, it doesn't when you try to modify the context actions (based on data changed) after the items have been displayed. And if you bind the Text Property of a ContextAction's MenuItem, if this property changes, the ContextAction MenuItem does reflect the change but does not close anymore which seems more like a bug to me. Anyway that does not fill the need for a simple use case with a "select" or "unselect" context action that would change based on item selection. I have yet to find a proper solution.

Comment: @Fred, You're missing a Proper Notification then. You should be using an ObservableCollection that will notify what/when data changes. I might suggest trying out [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) from James Montemagno

Comment: Thanks Dan for you answer. But no, I do have a proper ObservableCollection. Every bits of the cell do update immediately on the UI. That's not the real issue here. I'll try to post a full SO question in the next few days to explain my issue in greater details.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I'm having the same issue.  Has anyone been able to recreate or solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491528/trying-to-close-a-viewcell-contextaction-on-button-click-in-xamarin